# How to create a thread that listens for a state change?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I was spending my entire morning figuring out how Android threads and locks work. I have read about `Thread`, `Runnable`, `Handler`, `AsyncTask`, `Executors`, `HandlerThread`, `ThreadPoolExecutor`, and so on. I have also read about `Condition`, `Lock` and the method `synchronize`. But, I am still  hesitant about what type of thread should I use in my application.

Summarizing and simplifying, my app should do the following:

> A working thread will be attached to a specific `Fragment`, which displays a `GridLayout` with different elements. That thread should generate random numbers that corresponds with each one of the grid elements and send them sequentially to the parent `Fragment`, which will hide them a fixed number of milliseconds. However, the thread should be able to pause itself when user clicks a button in the `Fragment` (requiring a kind of synchronized usage).

The questions are the following:

1. What kind of Android thread is the most optimal in my case?
2. What is the best way to listen for a change in the state inside the thread loop if a user want to pause it?

For now, I am considering to extend the raw `Thread` class and use `synchronize()` to check the state, but I feel that it is not the most appropiate way to achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could be a good use case for `ThreadLocal`, with each "Grid Square" having its own `Thread` containing its own random number generator

Comment: @PPartisan It would be a great approach, but in this case the hiding should follow a sequence until all of them are hided. For instance, seq = [3 2 1 4] would hide the elements in that specific order, making necessary the use of a single thread that generates the sequence array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `RxJava` would be a good fit for this problem. I'm away from my IDE, but I envisage something where you:

1. Create a "Timer", with a random interval, for each individual item (say a `GridItemViewModel`) in your grid layout, and have it emit that item when it finishes.
2. Combine all those timers into a `List`.
3. Run all the timers simultaneously.
4. When each individual timer finishes, it emits its "item" (i.e. `ViewModel`). Use that to hide the appropriate item in your UI
5. When all items finish, it will trigger `onComplete()` in your overall `Observable`. When this is called, you know all tasks have fininshed.

So...

```
final List<Observable<Item>> tasks = gridItems()
    .stream()
    .map(item -> {
        final int seconds = ThreadLocalRandom.current().next(0, 5);
        return Observable.timer(seconds, TimeUnits.SECONDS).map(ignore -> item);
     })
    .collect(Collectors.toList());

Observable.merge(tasks)
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(item -> {
        //One item has completed. Take the "item" value
        // and use it to update your UI.
    }, t -> { /*No error handling*/}, () -> /*All items finished*/);
```